# Testing whether a node with particular content exists using xslt

Tags: xslt

I am trying to merge the  elements from two separate web.xml files using XSLT.  For example, if web-1.xml and web-2.xml are being merged, and I'm processing web-1.xml, I want all  elements in web-2.xml to be added into the result, except any that already exist in web-1.xml.

In the XSLT sheet, I have loaded the document whose servlet's are to be merged into the other document using:

```
<xsl:variable name="jandy" select="document('web-2.xml')"/>
```

I then have the following rule:

```
<xsl:template match="webapp:web-app">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!--  Copy all of the existing content from the document being processed  -->
    <xsl:apply-templates/>      

    <!--  Merge any <servlet> elements that don't already exist into the result  -->        
    <xsl:for-each select="$jandy/webapp:web-app/webapp:servlet">
      <xsl:variable name="servlet-name"><xsl:value-of select="webapp:servlet-name"/></xsl:variable>

      <xsl:if test="not(/webapp:web-app/webapp:servlet/webapp:servlet-name[text() = $servlet-name])">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>
```

The problem I'm having is getting the test in the if correct.  With the above code, the test always evaluates to false, whether a servlet-name element with the given node exists or not.  I have tried all kinds of different tests but with no luck.

The relevant files are available at http://www.cs.hope.edu/~mcfall/stackoverflow/web-1.xml,  and http://www.cs.hope.edu/~mcfall/stackoverflow/transform.xslt (the second web-2.xml is there as well, but StackOverflow won't let me post three links).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provide an anchor for the first document, just before the for-each loop:

```
<xsl:variable name="var" select="."/>
```

then, use it in your if:

```
<xsl:if test="not($var/webapp:servlet/webapp:servlet-name[text() = $servlet-name])">
```

Comment: This almost works; since the context node is a webapp:web-app, eliminating that part from the path after $var then works.  I'll give this the answer, but would really like to know why this makes a difference, as using the path starting with / seems like it should have done the same thing.

Comment: @ryanmcfall, you're right, I fixed the path.
As to why it works this way; it's all about context or, actually, scope. 
See [shadowing a variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Comment: As far as I can see, there is nothing in the original version I posted that depends on scope since that starts at the root node of the document.  The only way I can see it being a problem is if because the foreach is iterating over a nodeset from a different document, the / refers to that document rather than the desired one.  Is that it?

Comment: @ryanmcfall, yup, that's it. Inside the for-each loop, `/` refers to the root of the iteration elements. If that is a variable or an external document (accessed through a variable), then `/` refers to that variable's root or document's root respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your template matches XPATH `webapp:webapp` from `web-1.xml` and 
you are refencing absolute XPATH if your `xsl:if` condition: `/webapp:web-app/webapp:servlet/webapp:servlet-name[text() = $servlet-name]`. Try to do it using relative XPATH:

```
  <xsl:if test="not(webapp:servlet/webapp:servlet-name[text() = $servlet-name])">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
```

I haven't checked it, so you have to give it a try.

Also, it would be easier if you could provide web-1.xml and web-2.xml files.

EDIT

The following XSLT merges two files - the only problem appears when there are sections of the same type (like listener) in two places of the input XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:webapp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="jandy" select="document('web-2.xml')"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="web-app">
            <xsl:for-each select="webapp:web-app/*[(name() != preceding-sibling::node()[1]/name()) or (position() = 1)]">
                <xsl:variable name="nodeName" select="./name()"/>
                <xsl:variable name="web1" as="node()*">
                    <xsl:sequence select="/webapp:web-app/*[name()=$nodeName]"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="web2" as="node()*">
                    <xsl:sequence select="$jandy/webapp:web-app/*[name() = $nodeName]"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$web1" copy-namespaces="no"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$web2">
                    <xsl:variable name="text" select="./*[1]/text()"/>
                    <xsl:if test="count($web1[*[1]/text() = $text]) = 0">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: A relative path would be wrong; it would use the current context node, which is the node from the foreach, and would be looking in the wrong document.

I've posted links to the files if you want to download them.

Comment: I check the *.xml files you posted - there are no servlets that exist only in web-2.xml file.

Comment: Oops, wrong document saved as web-2.xml.  It is uploaded correctly now.